# How to access artifact from a different job

Tags: jenkins

I have the following artifact in `job-1`

[image]

I simply want to access the contents of what is inside this artifact?

Is there a way to do this in Groovy? I was thinking of using `curl`, but I am wondering if there is an easier way? Or is `curl` the easiest?

Comment: Are you try to execute the test.sh artifact from job-1 into job-2 and are these jobs within the same project?

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan, not execute, just read what is inside test.sh. And yes they are in the same project

Comment: You can use the plugin mentioned in the answer (_Copy Artifact_) and then I would also suggest that if you need artifact from a specific branch of the project (in case you have multibranch pipeline) then you can set it like so: `copyArtifacts(projectName: 'project-name/branch-name');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Copy Artifact plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/) should be able to cover your needs for this.